# Can the pattern argument in ls() be inverted?

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to get a vector of all the function names in the base package that contain only a `.` as punctuation, or no punctuation at all. I'd like to do it using only the `ls()` function.

`ls()` takes a `pattern` argument that is defined as

> an optional regular expression. Only names matching pattern are returned. `glob2rx` can be used to convert wildcard patterns to regular expressions.

I'm trying to invert my regular expression.  But I also want to keep the functions that contain `.`.  Here's an example of some of the ones I don't want.

```
lsBase1 <- ls("package:base", pattern = "[[:punct:]]")
head(lsBase1)
# [1] "^"   "~"   "<"   "<<-" "<="  "<-"
```

I want the inverted version of this, as if I was using `invert = TRUE` in `grep`, or by doing the following. **But** I also want the functions that contain only `.` if they contain punctuation.

```
lsBase2 <- ls("package:base")
lsBase2 <- lsBase[!grepl("[[:punct:]]", lsBase)]
head(lsBase2)
# [1] "abbreviate"      "abs"             "acos"            "acosh"          
# [5] "addNA"           "addTaskCallback"
```

Is there a way to invert the `pattern` argument in `ls()`?  Or, more generally can I invert the regular expression `[[:punct:]]` so it returns the opposite, but includes those matches that contain only `.` as punctuation?

Note:  More than one `.` is fine.

Another example of what I want is: Yes I want `is.vector` but no I don't want `[.data.frame`.

Comment: In most of the functions in the `package:base`, `.` signifies that the function is an S3 method. Is that what you mean by punctuation?

Comment: Yes, that would work too.  But I'd really like to do it in as few lines as possible.  `ls()` only if really possible

Comment: Use the source. If `pattern` is specified, `ls` basically just calls `grep`. So you could simply do that yourself and specify `invert=TRUE` like you want.

Comment: Why you don't use `^[[:alnum:].]+$` instead of trying to "negate" `[[:punct:]]` except for the dot?

Comment: I've honestly never used `alnum` before I don't think.  Didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Question is, should `1030` results return or `1060`?

Comment: @RichardScriven: No, it's 1026.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte -- Complicating things a bit, the number of matches will depend on the version of R you are using. I get, using the same pattern, 1025 matches in R-2.15.2, and 1029 in R-3.1.1. (BTW, +1 for your suggestion of the elegant `^[[:alnum:].]+$`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
m <- ls("package:base", pattern="^(\\.|[^[:punct:]])*$")
```

The `|` is regex for "OR", so in words, it says something like "match a sequence of characters, running from the start of the string to its end, each of which is either a `.`, OR not a punctuation character".

---

To confirm that this works:

```
## Dissolve the matched strings and check for any verboten characters.  
sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(m, ""))))
#  [1] "." "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "8" "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C" "d" "D" "e"
# [17] "E" "f" "F" "g" "G" "h" "H" "i" "I" "j" "J" "k" "K" "l" "L" "m"
# [33] "M" "n" "N" "o" "O" "p" "P" "q" "Q" "r" "R" "s" "S" "t" "T" "u"
# [49] "U" "v" "V" "w" "W" "x" "X" "y" "Y" "z"

## Have a look at (at least a few of) the names _excluded_ by the regex:
n <- setdiff(ls("package:base"), m)
sample(n, 10)
# [1] "names<-.POSIXlt" "[[<-.data.frame" "!.hexmode"       "$<-"            
# [5] "<-"              "&&"              "%*%"             "package_version"
# [9] "$"               "regmatches<-"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I  want...now how can I confirm it.  Haha, just kidding.

Answer (score 3):

The following will work for what you are asking.

```
> lsBase2[grepl('^([^\\pP\\pS]|\\.)+$', lsBase2, perl=T)]
```

Edit: Or you could simply use the following (R version 3.1.1) returns `1029` results on this:

```
> ls("package:base", pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$")
```

Comment: One would think that if a `pattern` argument is offered, then a `perl` argument would also be offered.  Strange that it's not like that in `ls`

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you think about it in steps.  First remove the `.` characters, then scan for additional punctuation:

```
lsBase2[!grepl('[[:punct:]]', gsub('[.]', '', lsBase2))]
```